# Iptables doesn't start

Tags: ubuntu, vesta

I can not start/restart iptables in the vestacp panel and ssh. When I press these buttons, the server hangs up and I have to restart it through the provider's panel. 
When I do this: service iptables start
Then I get the answer: Failed to start iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not found.

Please, tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have all of these rules in Vesta Admin Panel:

```
ACCEPTTCP/ EXIM25,5870.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTTCP/ SSH220.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTTCP/ WEB80,4430.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTTCP/ FTP21,12000-121000.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTUDP/ DNS530.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTTCP/ DNS530.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTTCP/ SMTP25,465,587,25250.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTTCP/ POP3110,9950.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTTCP/ IMAP143,9930.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTTCP/ DB3306,54320.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTTCP/ VESTA80830.0.0.0/0
ACCEPTICMP/ PING00.0.0.0/0
```

I didn't have the first one, after I added it, it started working.